# SQL: Get all posts with any comments (include 0)

Tags: sql

At this moment i have this query:

```
select p.idpost, count(c.idpost)
from posts p join comments c on p.idpost = c.idpost
group by p.idpost
```

The result only show posts with comments. How can i get **all** posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a LEFT JOIN:

```
select
    p.idpost,
    count(c.idpost)
from posts p
LEFT join comments c on p.idpost = c.idpost
group by p.idpost
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left join` instead of a `join`

```
select p.idpost, count(c.idpost)
from posts p 
    left join comments c on p.idpost = c.idpost
group by p.idpost
```

[Here is a good visual explanation of SQL joins with code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) It shows what happens with each join